# Heroku b fail installing dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku

I would like to deploy my react app on Heroku, and I pushed my code to a git repository. when I run `git push heroku main` command to deploy the project, it fails to install dependencies, and I receive this error message:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. heroku/nodejs
remote:        2. https://github.com/mars/create-reactapp-buildpack.got
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 16.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.16.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 8.11.0
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! code EUSAGE
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: react@18.2.0 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: react-dom@18.2.0 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: loose-envify@1.4.0 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: js-tokens@4.0.0 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: scheduler@0.23.0 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Clean install a project
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Usage:
remote:        npm ERR! npm ci
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Options:
remote:        npm ERR! [--no-audit] [--foreground-scripts] [--ignore-scripts]
remote:        npm ERR! [--script-shell <script-shell>]
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Rs1UF/_logs/2022-08-02T02_46_25_097Z-debug-0.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
```

I tried lots of ways, but none of them solved the issue. Does anybody know how I can fix it?

Comment: you should say what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

for resolving:

```
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
```

you should specify your node and npm versions in `package.json` file. for example:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.13.1",
    "npm": ">=8.2.0"
  },
```

and as it say:

```
remote:        npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
```

use `npm install` (if did not work, you can delete `package-lock.json` and try again)